# Typescript set value type from function

Tags: typescript

This is probably simple but I couldn't find an answer, any help is appreciated!  I'm trying to have a function assert a value type for a variable, I was wondering if that's possible through typescript:

checking not null

```
function isNull(val: any) {
    return val == null
}
function fn( val: string | null ) {
    // if (val == null) return // works
    if (isNull(val)) return // doesn't work
    val.split(",")
}
```

checking if var is a number

```
function isNumber(val: any) {
    return val == "number"
}
function fn2(  val: string | number ) {
    // if (typeof val == "number") return // works
    if (isNumber(val)) return // doesn't work
    val.split(",")
}
```

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAE8DOA5RtPgDb4AUAbgIb4BcKZkAngJQoDewK7KATgKaziepy%20FAEIAvCkgF8wAL5gocJKlCQiKIdXSxO8SAHMUAH0nSUTVhxQB6a2lApSFFGIlTCTHnwE27Ad0ROAGt0Ng54ByIMbFxpJ3wGT15%20VFsUABNEbnRIAHJYFADgsPYhADp0AAd8eFgiACIAGnqGORAFGARkNCxwAFsAI25OeOpaRhYSrmSfIRcJeqlB4fq2iE7lFFUAJnUNCi0dPUMTJaHOc0mrNIjHWDpK7kQHOdcURf7zlunvVP9AkJTW5RXrLEZCRI-FK%20DJZHL5QoAqblKo1OpNFpyIA)

Comment: [Use a custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the functions *type guards*, to indicate to the TypeScript compiler that truthy values returned indicate that the parameter is a particular type:

```
function isNull(val: any): val is null {
    return val == null
}
```

```
function isNumber(val: any): val is number {
    return typeof val == "number"
}
```

(note that you need to use `typeof val`, not just `val` in the `isNumber` there)

Comment: Thanks this is perfect